# Make use of BehaviorSubject's first value pulled from backend - default value

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have 3 main `BehaviorSubject`: `user`, `organizations`,`selectedOrganization`.

You first need to get the user from the backend and then get his organizations and then select the first organization (this is why I'm using `flatMap`). All this in `user.service.ts`:

```
user = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

constructor(private http: Http, public settings: SettingsService, public organizationService: OrganizationService) {
  this.setUserData();
}

  setUserData() {

  return this.organizationService.getAssignedOrganizations()
  .flatMap(
    (organizationResponse) => {
      this.organizationDataInfo = organizationResponse;
      return this.getUserInformation();
    }
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.user.next(data);
      this.organizationService.organizations.next(this.organizationDataInfo);
      this.organizationService.selectedOrganization.next(this.organizationDataInfo[0]); //<------ here we set the selectedOrganization, our main thing.
    }
  );

}
```

We declare the other 2 `BehaviorSubject` in `organizations.service.ts`:

```
  organizations = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  selectedOrganization = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
```

And now, I want to make use of this `selectedOrganization` in a component by using his id to make other api calls on the backend:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.organizationService.selectedOrganization.subscribe((val) => {

          this.selectedOrganization = val;
          this.orderService.getOrders("apicall/"+this.selectedOrganization.id)
          .subscribe(res=> console.log(res))
      });
}
```

There is no initial value for `selectedOrganization` because it will get data from the `user.service.ts` constructor (this is where I am doing it wrong). If I will add a timeout of 1 sec it will receive the Subject's value.

How can I fix this without timeouting it?

This can be resolved using `APP_INITIALIZER`, so I can call `setUserData()` before loading the app **but** before using this method I need to login into my app = not working.

Comment: Why are you not calling `setUserData` from component instead? You could chain all requests.

Comment: I have multiple components on the same page. If I load this in header (let's assume) other components will need those values. I need to define them as 'default values' before loading the app (but not with APP_INITIALIZER)

Comment: What do you mean with 'default values'?

Comment: The values are asynchronously retrieved from back end with `setUserData`, A service is used by components that expect initial value (default) to exist on service injection. Initial value should be retrieved and assigned before these components are instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake in your code, which is:

```
this.selectedOrganization = val;
```

selectedOrganization is a BehaviorSubject observer, you can't use it like this. So call the id of selected organization by using val.id

And the one solution to your problem could be, just check for an empty value, if it's empty then skip the call. So your code will be like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.organizationService.selectedOrganization.subscribe((val) => {
    if(val !== ' '){
      this.orderService.getOrders("apicall/"+val.id)
        .subscribe(res=> console.log(res))
    }
  });
}
```

The other solution, which I think, will be more suitable to your situation is setting a boolean flag. So in your user.service.ts:

```
public isDataSet: Boolean = false;  //1
setUserData() {
  return this.organizationService.getAssignedOrganizations()
    .flatMap(
      (organizationResponse) => {
        this.organizationDataInfo = organizationResponse;
        return this.getUserInformation();
      }
    )
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user.next(data);
        this.organizationService.organizations.next(this.organizationDataInfo);
        this.organizationService.selectedOrganization.next(this.organizationDataInfo[0]);
        this.isDataSet = true;  //2
      }
    );
  }
```

So here in (1) you declare a boolean variable **isDataSet** and set the initial value to false. And in (2) **getAssignedOrganizations** you are setting that to true whenever you get data. So in (3) your component, you can check for **isDataSet** which is true only when you get the data and your component will be like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.organizationService.selectedOrganization.subscribe((val) => {
    if(this.userService.isDataSet){ . //3
      this.orderService.getOrders("apicall/"+val.id)
        .subscribe(res=> console.log(res))
      this.userService.isDataSet = false;  //4
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this one helps you.